# image of eyes to brain

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neurology

If the eyes image is upside down before brain processes it, then do that mean an alzeiheimers patient in end stage see images upside down at all time because of a deteriorating brain?

Comment: I think you might want to do a bit more research on how alzheimer's affects the brain. It doesn't go after the brain's visual pathway from what I understand.

Comment: @StevenJeuris et al. - I don't share your verdict that this is a dupe of the linked question. This question focuses on Alzheimer and more broadly whether brain degeneration may lead to "unflipped" images. Not the most rigorously researched question, perhaps based on a faulty presupposition, but not a dupe.

Comment: @AliceD I considered that as well. It is one of those 'not fully a dupe', but the answer of the duplicate question most likely does answer the OP's question. If not, the OP is free to update his question taking this new information into account to disambiguate more clearly after which it can be reopened.